# Can we create accessible diagrams using mxgraph?

Tags: accessibility, mxgraph

I am evaluating mxgraph library to create and modify diagrams on web page. Looking at the API documentation, I am not able to figure out if it is possible to achieve accessibility using mxgraph library. For e.x, is it possible to use keyboard tab navigation to select objects/elements and then drag them on the drawing area? is it possible to tab navigate on diagram elements/shapes on the drawing area and use keyboard events handlers(like launch properties panel on enter/space key press)?

Answer (score 0):

There is several key handlers that you can use on the mxgraph. In this case i will use the [Grapheditor](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html) as an example.

This is the `EditorUI.js` file and you can see some of the key handlers that he have

```
    keyHandler.bindAction(8, false, 'delete'); // Backspace
    keyHandler.bindAction(8, true, 'deleteAll'); // Backspace
    keyHandler.bindAction(46, false, 'delete'); // Delete
    keyHandler.bindAction(46, true, 'deleteAll'); // Ctrl+Delete
    keyHandler.bindAction(72, true, 'resetView'); // Ctrl+H
    keyHandler.bindAction(72, true, 'fitWindow', true); // Ctrl+Shift+H
    keyHandler.bindAction(74, true, 'fitPage'); // Ctrl+J
    keyHandler.bindAction(74, true, 'fitTwoPages', true); // Ctrl+Shift+J
    keyHandler.bindAction(48, true, 'customZoom'); // Ctrl+0
    keyHandler.bindAction(82, true, 'turn'); // Ctrl+R
    keyHandler.bindAction(82, true, 'clearDefaultStyle', true); // Ctrl+Shift+R
    keyHandler.bindAction(83, true, 'save'); // Ctrl+S
    keyHandler.bindAction(83, true, 'saveAs', true); // Ctrl+Shift+S
    keyHandler.bindAction(65, true, 'selectAll'); // Ctrl+A
    keyHandler.bindAction(65, true, 'selectNone', true); // Ctrl+A
    keyHandler.bindAction(73, true, 'selectVertices', true); // Ctrl+Shift+I
    keyHandler.bindAction(69, true, 'selectEdges', true); // Ctrl+Shift+E
    keyHandler.bindAction(69, true, 'editStyle'); // Ctrl+E
    keyHandler.bindAction(66, true, 'bold'); // Ctrl+B
    keyHandler.bindAction(66, true, 'toBack', true); // Ctrl+Shift+B
    keyHandler.bindAction(70, true, 'toFront', true); // Ctrl+Shift+F
    keyHandler.bindAction(68, true, 'duplicate'); // Ctrl+D
    keyHandler.bindAction(68, true, 'setAsDefaultStyle', true); // Ctrl+Shift+D
    keyHandler.bindAction(90, true, 'undo'); // Ctrl+Z
    keyHandler.bindAction(89, true, 'autosize', true); // Ctrl+Shift+Y
    keyHandler.bindAction(88, true, 'cut'); // Ctrl+X
    keyHandler.bindAction(67, true, 'copy'); // Ctrl+C
    keyHandler.bindAction(86, true, 'paste'); // Ctrl+V
    keyHandler.bindAction(71, true, 'group'); // Ctrl+G
    keyHandler.bindAction(77, true, 'editData'); // Ctrl+M
    keyHandler.bindAction(71, true, 'grid', true); // Ctrl+Shift+G
    keyHandler.bindAction(73, true, 'italic'); // Ctrl+I
    keyHandler.bindAction(76, true, 'lockUnlock'); // Ctrl+L
    keyHandler.bindAction(76, true, 'layers', true); // Ctrl+Shift+L
    keyHandler.bindAction(80, true, 'formatPanel', true); // Ctrl+Shift+P
    keyHandler.bindAction(85, true, 'underline'); // Ctrl+U
    keyHandler.bindAction(85, true, 'ungroup', true); // Ctrl+Shift+U
    keyHandler.bindAction(190, true, 'superscript'); // Ctrl+.
    keyHandler.bindAction(188, true, 'subscript'); // Ctrl+,
    keyHandler.bindKey(13, function () {
```

Of course you can **create new key handlers** using the `EditorUi.prototype.createKeyHandler`

You should access the [grapheditor](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html) and see if that works for you

You can also take a look at the docs [here](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/handler/mxKeyHandler-js.html)